# Not able to print with two decimals

Tags: python

I am solving a problem in hackerrank , and i cannot print a output with two decimal places.

I have tried round(number,2) and -

```
avg=(toavg[0]+toavg[1]+toavg[2])/3
print(float("{0:.2f}".format((toavg[0]+toavg[1]+toavg[2])/3)))
```

I am using python 3.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()
    toavg=student_marks[query_name]
    avg=(toavg[0]+toavg[1]+toavg[2])/3
    print(float("{0:.2f}".format((toavg[0]+toavg[1]+toavg[2])/3)))
```

I expected 56.00 or 36.50 but i got 56.0 or 36.5.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using `"{0:.2f}".format()` which returns a string and then converting that string to a float with `float()`. What you should do is just use `"{0:.2f}".format()`:

```
print("{0:.2f}".format((toavg[0]+toavg[1]+toavg[2])/3))
```

Comment: Thank you . Is there any other way to do this using python 3?

Comment: The code on my answer works for Python 3. You can also do `print("%0.2f" % (toavg[0]+toavg[1]+toavg[2])/3))` if you want (it's the same).